# Linux Platform: Enlarge video screen size N times

Tags: linux, video, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I am looking for a application on Linux platforms (Ubuntu/CentOS etc) that can enlarge video size N times. N could be any number, like 1.5, 4 etc

For example, if I have a video with screen size 100*200, I want to make it 1.5 times larger, that will be: 150*300. Of course, I will expect the video quality to drop but it doesnt matter.

I am not sure whether ffmpeg has this function but a quick Google lands me nowhere. So I am here now.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

See mplayer and its -xy option.